# Response.body doesn't return anything with supertest, but works fine in server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, supertest

I am trying to test my app with supertest. When I run `nodemon index.js`, and go to the address to make a GET request, I get a working response with correct data.
Supertest is called with `app.js`, which it's contents are down below as well. 
But when I do that, response body returns `[]`. Why might that be? I'm new to all this, so if anything must be added, please say so.

index.js:

```
const app = require('./app') // the actual Express app
const http = require('http')
const config = require('./utils/config')

const server = http.createServer(app)

server.listen(config.PORT, () => {
  console.log('Server running')
})
```

app.js:

```
const config = require('./utils/config')
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const blogsRouter = require('./controllers/blogs')
const middleware = require('./utils/middleware')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

console.log('connecting to', config.MONGODB_URI)

mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('connected to MongoDB')
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('error connection to MongoDB:', error.message)
  })

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.static('build'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(middleware.requestLogger)

app.use('/api/blogs', blogsRouter)

app.use(middleware.unknownEndpoint)
app.use(middleware.errorHandler)

module.exports = app
```

Here is the part that I run test:
blog_api.test.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const supertest = require('supertest')
const app = require('../app')

const api = supertest(app)

test('blogs are returned as json', async () => {
  await api
    .get('/api/blogs')
    .expect(200)
    .expect('Content-Type', /application\/json/)
})

test('there are one blog', async () => {
    const response = await api.get('/api/blogs')
    //response doesn't return anything yet works fine in server?
    expect(response.body.length).toBe(1)
  })


afterAll(() => {
  mongoose.connection.close()
})
```

first test works fine but second one fails because response.body returns `[]`.

Just for good measure, here is the code where I actually define what the GET request should do:
in my controller:

```
blogsRouter.get('/', (request, response) => {
    Blog.find({}).then(notes => {
        let resJson = response.json(notes.map(note => note.toJSON()))

        return resJson
    })
})
```